# R data.table divide set of columns and flag using any

Tags: r, data.table, apply, lapply, any

I am working on a data set which is large and having many columns. I am using data.table to speed up the calculations. However at certain points I am not sure how to go about and convert my data.table back to data.frame and do the calculation. This slows up the process. It would help a lot to have suggestions on how I can write the below in data.table. Below is a snap of my code on a dummy data -

```
library(data.table)

#### set the seed value
set.seed(9901)

#### create the sample variables for creating the data
p01 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p02 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p03 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p04 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p05 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p06 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)
p07 <- sample(1:100,1000,replace = T)

#### create the data.table
data <- data.table(cbind(p01,p02,p03,p04,p05,p06,p07))

###user input for last column
lcol <- 6

###calculate start column as last - 3
scol <- lcol-3

###calculate average for scol:lcol
data <- data[,avg:= apply(.SD,1,mean,na.rm=T),.SDcols=scol:lcol]

###converting to data.frame since do not know the solution in data.table
data <- as.data.frame(data)

###calculate the trend in percentage
data$t01 <- data[,lcol-00]/data[,"avg"]-1
data$t02 <- data[,lcol-01]/data[,"avg"]-1
data$t03 <- data[,lcol-02]/data[,"avg"]-1
data$t04 <- data[,lcol-03]/data[,"avg"]-1
data$t05 <- data[,lcol-04]/data[,"avg"]-1

###converting back to data.table
data <- as.data.table(data)

###calculate the min and max for the trend
data1 <- data[,`:=` (trend_min = apply(.SD,1,min,na.rm=T),
                     trend_max = apply(.SD,1,max,na.rm=T)),.SDcols=c(scol:lcol)]

###calculate flag if any of t04 OR t05 is an outlier for min and max values. This would be many columns in actual data

data1$flag1 <- ifelse(data1$t04 < data1$trend_min | data1$t04 > data1$trend_max,1,0)
data1$flag2 <- ifelse(data1$t05 < data1$trend_min | data1$t05 > data1$trend_max,1,0)

data1$flag <- ifelse(data1$flag1 == 1 | data1$flag2 == 1,1,0)
```

So basically, how can I -

1. calculate the percentages based on user input of column index. Note it is not simple divide but percentage
2. How can I create the flag variable....I think I need to use any function but not sure how....

Comment: I would change the `apply(.SD, 1, mean` to `data[, aveg := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = ..]` and `min/max` calculation to `do.call(pmin, .SD)` and `do.call(pmax, .SD)`  I think these steps would greatly enhance your efficiency

Comment: @akrun, thank you for your suggestion....I had to calculate SD as well and I was not getting anything like rowSD so to keep it consistent I used apply....Any additional benefits  of using rowMeans?

Comment: There is `rowSDs` if you convert it to matrix from `matrixStats`

Comment: @akrun, Thank you for letting me know. Will explore this option

Comment: I posted as a solution.  can you please check .t thanks

Comment: Based on your code for the ifelse, it is doing on the same 't04' is it a typo,.  You meant t05?

Comment: @akrun Thank you for pointing it out. Updated the code it should be t05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some steps can be made more efficient, i.e. instead of using the `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`, the `mean`, `min`, `max` can be replaced with `rowMeans`, `pmin`, `pmax`

```
library(data.table)
data[ , avg:= rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) ,.SDcols=scol:lcol]
data[,   sprintf('t%02d', 1:5) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/avg -1), 
          .SDcol = patterns("^p0[1-5]")]
data[,`:=` (trend_min = do.call(pmin, c(.SD,na.rm=TRUE)),
            trend_max =  do.call(pmax, c(.SD,na.rm=TRUE)) ),.SDcols=c(scol:lcol)]
data
#      p01 p02 p03 p04 p05 p06 p07   avg         t01         t02        t03         t04        t05 trend_min trend_max
#   1:  35  53  22  82 100  59  69 65.75 -0.46768061 -0.19391635 -0.6653992  0.24714829  0.5209125        22       100
#   2:  78  75  15  65  70  69  66 54.75  0.42465753  0.36986301 -0.7260274  0.18721461  0.2785388        15        70
#   3:  15  45  27  61  63  75  99 56.50 -0.73451327 -0.20353982 -0.5221239  0.07964602  0.1150442        27        75
#   4:  41  80  13  22  63  84  17 45.50 -0.09890110  0.75824176 -0.7142857 -0.51648352  0.3846154        13        84
#   5:  53   9  75  47  25  75  66 55.50 -0.04504505 -0.83783784  0.3513514 -0.15315315 -0.5495495        25        75
#  ---                                                                                                                
# 996:  33  75   9  61  74  55  57 49.75 -0.33668342  0.50753769 -0.8190955  0.22613065  0.4874372         9        74
# 997:  24  68  74  11  43  75  37 50.75 -0.52709360  0.33990148  0.4581281 -0.78325123 -0.1527094        11        75
# 998:  62  78  82  97  56  50  74 71.25 -0.12982456  0.09473684  0.1508772  0.36140351 -0.2140351        50        97
# 999:  70  88  93   4  39  75  93 52.75  0.32701422  0.66824645  0.7630332 -0.92417062 -0.2606635         4        93
#1000:  20  50  99  94  62  66  98 80.25 -0.75077882 -0.37694704  0.2336449  0.17133956 -0.2274143        62        99
```

and then create the 'flag'

```
data[,  flag := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
      x < trend_min| x > trend_max))), .SDcols = t04:t05]
```

Comment: Thank you bro!! You make it so simple....could you please confirm why we need the + sign?

Comment: How about if we need to calculate the percentage based on the previous columns...so what would I need to change in `lapply(.SD, function(x) x/avg -1)` ....I mean I want to replace *avg* with the previous column, tried replacing with x-1 but does not work.....Please suggest.

Comment: @user1412 It is just to coerce the logical to binary i.e `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`  or it can be done with `as.integer`.  Perhaps you want `Map(`/`, .SD[, -1, with = FALSE], .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE)`

Comment: thank you for your revert....I tried by replacing the lapply function with Map function, however I am getting the error, "Error in `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(sprintf("t%02d", 1:5), Map("/", .SD[,  : 
  Supplied 5 columns to be assigned 4 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2." 
I have been searching on the net for this error but not getting the answer....Could you please help understand the problem and how to resolve it.code I am running `data[,   sprintf('t%02d', 1:5) := Map('/', .SD[, -1, with = FALSE], .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE]),
              .SDcol = patterns("^p0[1-5]")]`

Comment: @user1412 Here, you are doing the division for 4 columns.  So you need `data[, sprintf('t%02d', 1:4) :=  Map(`/`, .SD[, -1, with = FALSE], .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE]), .SDcol = patterns("^p0[1-5]")]`

Comment: thank you for revert. Yes I do not get the error. Only last thing, this is dividing correctly, but how do I get the percentage...I mean where would I need to put -1 ?

Comment: @user1412 I am not sure about the calculation you needed for percentage.  is it `100 * x/sum(x)`

Comment: it is same as earlier `x/avg -1` now we are replacing **avg** with previous column....which we are able to do with Map, but that is only dividing...how to I apply the -1 ?

Comment: Just do `Map(function(x, y) x/y -1, .SD[-1, with = FALSE], .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE])`

Comment: Thank you so much...you made it so simple....Lot to learn from you :)

Comment: Sorry I missed to clarify about -1 and -ncol in .`SD[ ]` I think -ncol would pickup the previous column...but not sure what and -1 does. Could you please help clarifying the same.

Comment: @user1412  Here the `-ncol` it is removing the last column and `-1` is removing the first column of `.SD`.  It is make the lengths same

Comment: thank you for clarifying. This is great way of solving the requirement. from where we come to know what all can be used in .SD?

Comment: @user1412 `.SD` is a mini data.table within in the Data.table, where the columns are the only one specified in `.SDcols`.  So, you can use it as the same syntax as in a data.table.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying !!